# Failed to run a new application with exit code:1

Tags: meteor

## please forward my following answer to [node.js: Mongodb db.collection.find() not working while collection.insert works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088663/node-js-mongodb-db-collection-find-not-working-while-collection-insert-works)

you did use: collection.find({name:req.body.name}).limit(1).size()
1 you can also use cursor variable for limit. or different syntax from mongo shell.
2  or use the cursor var  within your javascript file(see below):

### ------------------------------------------------

1
(mongo-shell)> db.collection.find({name:req.body.name},{$limit:1,$skip:10})
                 or:

> db.collection.find({name:req.body.name},"$limit":1,"$skip":10})

## or better use the cursor var  within your js file:

```
var query = {name:req.body.name}
var cursor=db.collection.find(query);
cursor.sort({"name":1});`enter code here`
cursor.limit(10);
cursor.skip(100);
```

Comment: Did you follow the advice that was likely printed when you created the project and the suggestion in your error output? `meteor npm i` and `meteor npm install --save babel-runtime`?

Comment: it helped meteor works ok - however using node and express + some other packages is sufficient even not the fastest response time is enough for most cases