# How to insert documents if they don't already exist from within a remote method in MongoDb using LoopBack

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm very new to MongoDB (about 4 days in) and I'm trying to insert documents into my collection from within a remote method using Loopback without adding duplicate documents.

I firstly tested adding documents as such:

```
Events.create(resultData);
```

Which worked without issue.

I then moved on to trying to add a document without adding duplicates [a few other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801008/mongodb-insert-if-not-exists):

```
Events.update(data,data,{upsert: true});
```

However, this did not add anything to the database.

I decided to move on and try and see if I could first check to see if a document could be found from a collection and therefore not add the document. Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389811/how-to-query-mongodb-to-test-if-an-item-exists).

```
if(Events.find({itemOfData: resultData.itemOfData},{limit: 1}).size < 1){
    Events.create(resultData);
}
```

However, as before it doens't create any documents.

I'm not sure what to try next or whether my implementation of the above solutions is faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Events.update(data,data,{upsert: true});`

LoopBack models don't expose MongoDB API. Methods like `create` are providing database-agnostic API that's mapped by connectors to database commands.

If you want to insert a document only if it does not exist, you can use one of the following methods (depending on what you are trying to achieve):

- `replaceOrCreate`
- `patchOrCreate` (also known as `upsert` and `updateOrCreate`)
- `findOrCreate`
- `upsertWithWhere`

> `if(Events.find({itemOfData: resultData.itemOfData},{limit: 1}).size < 1){`

The `find` method accepts a Filter object (see [Querying data](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html)) which contains not only the condition for matching records, but also things like pagination and what related models to include. The condition is stored in `where` property of the Filter object.

Also the `find` method returns a Promise, you need to wait until it's resolved before counting the number of returned records.

```js
const found = Events.find({
  where: {itemOfData: resultData.itemOfData}
  limit: 1
});
if (found.size < 1){
  // ...
}
```

While the solution based on `find` may seem to work well in development, it introduces a race condition where two "same" records can be created when the application is under high load. Whenever possible, it's advised to use built-in functions like `patchOrCreate` that use database-specific means to guarantee atomicity.